# Java Recursion Triangle Standing on Tip

Tags: java, recursion, geometry

I was wondering how to create triangle out of asterisks on its tip rather than on its base.

I have the code for making it stand on its base:

```
    public static String printTriangle (int count) 
{
    if( count <= 0 ) return "";

    String p = printTriangle(count - 1);
    p = p + "*";
    System.out.print(p);
    System.out.print("\n");

    return p;
 }
```

But then I'm stuck on how to have the greatest number of stars on the top, and then the next least, and so on.  I was thinking something along the terms of having (count - p) to have the input of rows be subtracted from the amount of decrease, but then i was confused by this idea because p is string.

EDIT:  I tried changing the position of printTriangle(count - 1) using my original method without iterations and got 1 star per each line; how can I fix this?

```
public class triangles 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    printTriangle(5);
}
public static String printTriangle (int count) 
{
    if( count <= 0 ) return "";
      String p = "";
    p = p + "*";
    System.out.print(p);
    System.out.print("\n");
     p = printTriangle(count - 1);
    return p;

         }


}
```

Comment: "and got 1 star per each line; how can I fix this?" that is because you only print 1 "*" per 1 recursion call (which adds a new line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are missing a loop inside the recursive function to add the correct number on *s for each line.

```
  public static String printTriangle (int count) 
  {
      if( count <= 0 ) return "";

      String p = printTriangle(count - 1);
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
      {
        p = p + "*";
      }

      p += "\n";
      return p;
   }
```

and calling code to look like

```
String triangle = printTriangle(4);
System.out.println(triangle);
```

it produces

```
*
**
***
****
```

Also I would use a StringBuilder and not a string for this purpose.

Just reread you question.

in you were after a triangle like this

```
****
***
**
*
```

You need to change when recursion is called.

ie

```
  public static String printTriangle (int count) 
  {
      if( count <= 0 ) return "";

      String p="";
      for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
      {
        p = p + "*";
      }

      p += "\n";
      return p + printTriangle(count - 1);
   }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using a string instead of a stringBuilder and without any iterations?

Comment: Ill post my attempt at doing so in the question/

Comment: for such a trivial example you do not have to use StringBuilder but it is the correct way to append strings.

Comment: anything iterative can be achieved through recursion and vice versa. So in theory you could replace the iterations by calling a recursive function that would just print the *s for the current line

Comment: using pure recursion you need to do it in 2 functions.     
  public static String printLine (int count) 
  {
    if( count <= 0 ) return "";

    return "*" + printLine(count-1);
  }
  
  public static String printTriangle (int count) 
  {
      if( count <= 0 ) return "";

      String p="";
      
      p = printLine(count);
      
      p += "\n";
      return p + printTriangle(count - 1);
   }

Answer (score 0):

@Leon, though your answer is correct it has missed a part of his question.

Edit: @Leon, it seems you've updated your answer. Mine is no longer needed.

For a triangle standing on its tip try the following

```
public static String printTriangle (int count) 
{
  if( count <= 0 ) return "";

  String p = "";
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
    p = p + "*";
  }
  p += "\n";

  p += printTriangle(count - 1)

  return p;
}
```

Comment: yeah i realised as I was pasting the answer from eclipse